# Telerik RadGrid $find returns null after jquery dialog is closed

Tags: jquery, telerik, webforms, telerik-grid

I have a checkbox that, when clicked, checks or un-checks all the checkboxes that exists in a Telerik RadGrid.

```
function CheckAll(sender, args) {
        // Set all the checkboxes according to the master
        $(":checkbox").attr("checked", sender.get_checked());

        // If "check all", do some other stuff
        if(sender.get_checked())
        {
            var masterTable = $find("<%=gridSubmittedRequests.ClientID%>").get_masterTableView();
            var rows = masterTable.get_dataItems(); // row collection
            // do some other stuff                
        }
    }
}
```

This all works fine until I open (and close) a jquery dialog, after which

```
$find("<%=gridSubmittedRequests.ClientID%>")
```

returns null. Hence, I can never get to the important `// do some other stuff` part.

The jQuery dialog close function doesn't do anything special:

```
$("#divProcessModal").dialog(
        {
            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: { 
                "Process request(s)": function (e) { 
                    // process requests
                },
                "Close without processing": function (e) { 
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                }
            },
            title: "Process Request(s)",
        });
```

All I do is click the `Close without processing` button.
Things I've tried include registering the script on the server side, and setting the mastertable as a global variable, but without success.

**Update**

I figured out what the cause is. The content of the jquery dialog is another page

```
$("#divProcessModal").load("/ProcessRequests.aspx?requestList="+requestList);
```

This page has its own form, code-behind and all that, and that seems to cause the problem. I guess I can move all the functionality in `ProcessRequests.aspx` to the current aspx page, but if anyone can explain what is happening and why my initial approach doesn't work, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is the dialog content in the middle of a form?

Comment: The container <div> is in the main form, but when I open the dialog I don't append it to the form. I tried appending it (which I otherwise don't have any need for), but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the cause is. The content of the jquery dialog is another page

`$("#divProcessModal").load("/ProcessRequests.aspx?requestList="+requestList);`
This page has its own form, code-behind and all that, and that seems to cause the problem. Moving all the functionality in ProcessRequests.aspx to the current aspx page solves the problem.